# Column issue when refactoring from aspx to cshtml (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am in the process of converting my website from aspx to cshtml (Razor). This is going fine apart from an issue I have with my 2 or 3 column master pages and trying to convert these to a cshtml Layout Page.

In Razor I have basically created separate pages for all of my sections and am then calling these from the Layout Page using @RenderPage. Maybe this in itself is wrong? Basically what all the sections are displaying fine apart from the Main content section which is basically a wrapper for the 3 (or 2) columns that I wish to be displayed within this. I have tried various ways to do this but either just get the 1 main column displayed across the width of the page or get the column displayed above each other but the formatting of the other 2 is incorrect. I know all of the CSS etc works fine in aspx but I am obviously doing something wrong in Razor.

CSHTML New Layout Page

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top">
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Top.cshtml")
        </div>
        <div id="header">
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Nav.cshtml")
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Main.cshtml")

            <div class="columnVerySmall">
                @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_ColumnVerySmall.cshtml", false)
            </div>

            <div id="columnLarge">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>

            <div id="columnSmall">
                @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_ColumnSmall.cshtml", false)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml")
        </div>

        <div id="scripts">
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Scripts.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Old ASPX Master Page:

```
<div class="main">
<main role ="main" class="mainWrapper">
        <div class="columnVerySmall">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="columnVerySmallContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="columnLarge">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="columnLargeContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>                       
        <div class="columnSmall">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="columnSmallContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by changing the Main section as shown in the code block below. I basically added the "Main" code to my layout and then @Render for the Columns. I don't really see how I can do this by having a separate page for "Main" and then calling it from the Layout Page using @RenderPage as I was originally trying. This is what I changed:

```
    <div class="main">
        <main role="main" class="mainWrapper">
            <div class="columnVerySmall">
                @RenderPage("_ColumnVerySmall.cshtml")                  
            </div>
            <div class="columnLarge">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <div class="columnSmall">
                @RenderPage("_ColumnSmall.cshtml")
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
```